# PC running hot only in the morning

Tags: windows, temperature

I've noticed that my old Lenovo laptop (running two different Windows versions: Windows 10 1909 as default on one partition; Windows Server 2019 on another partition tends to run hot in the morning, between, say 8 am and 10:30 am, regardless of what I do with it, and regardless of the OS that's active.

Sometimes, the PC will even remain idle for about 20 to 30 minutes, and still run hot, as advertised by the ThinkPad Fan Control temperature icon sitting in the tray.

I suspect some maintenance tasks running in the background are causing the CPU to run hot, but when I look at the services and processes list in Process Hacker, for example, or even Task Manager, CPU usage remains low, at around 10-15 %.

Lots of I/O, though, so maybe it's Windows Defender doing some secret stuff behind the scenes?

This never happens at night. For example, right now, I have Firefox opened with four tabs, two for Twitter and its notifications (push activated), Thunderbird polling my four email accounts every 10 minutes, and the CPU temp stays at around 60 degrees Celsius.

Same conditions this morning, CPU temps were well over 75 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Other than this Lenovo software, what software have you used, to benchmark your system?  Edit your question rather then submit the information as a comment.

Comment: I didn't benchmark it per se. I just watched as the temp icon turned to yellow, then orange, then red, as the CPU temperature kept rising and rising. FWIW, ThinkPad Fan Control isn't a Lenovo soft, it's a third-party that's been around for years, and does a very good job at keeping fans at a reasonable level. With the exact same settings, programs running et al, CPU and bus temps at night and in the morning can differ by a solid 15° C sometimes. There must be a reason for that.

Comment: "ThinkPad" is owned by Lenovo, so I take it by that response, you have used no other software to verify the temperatures being reported are accurate?  Does this happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: Is the laptop in the sun during the morning?

Comment: In Safe Mode, TPF (ThinkPad Fan Control) won't lauch, even though it's registered as a service and running as SYSTEM. I don't know why, but I seldom go into Safe Mode anyway. When I do, the fan (singular) screams like a banshee because it's in BIOS mode, which can't be edited or altered in any way. Several other software that monitor CPU and bus temps give off the same readings, be them ThrottleStop, SpeedFan and a bunch of others, so I take it it's not a sensor issue, and even if it was, why such a difference between morning and evening? EDIT: no, the laptop is in my desk, away from sunlight.

Comment: Have you checked for malware? E.G., a coin miner might be using CPU at certain times.

Comment: @moishe: no, I haven't, I must say, and I honestly don't know where to start if that's what's happening... I use Windows Defender on both OSes, and so far, no issues in the malware department. I use Firefox as default browser, and even when playing with priority, reduced working set etc... I don't see a difference, except in the morning, my PC runs hot, and not in the evening. How can I check for coin miner software?

Comment: I'd like to post a screenshot but it's impossible in a comment: right now, the CPU temp is hovering between 75 and 80° C, and there seems to be a lot of service/OS activity, as demonstrated by the green band in the Process Hacker (user processes are in red). Temp has just gone down to 65-68° C, but it'll come back up, as it does every morning. Last night, when I replied to your comment, it was steady at 55-60° C. I checked on maintenance tasks, and none is set to go off at that time of day. :-(

Comment: This might seem silly, but have you checked and recorded the exact ambient air temperatures at both points?  Another environmental factor to consider might be air flow / HVAC, e.g., A/C set to turn on at specific times, which can impact cooling efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that no application is launched other than those who automaticaly launch at startup.

When the computer is "cold", look at the launched processes and take a screenshot.  One ordered by CPU usage then another one by memory usage.

See those who are on top of the CPU and memory usage.

Then when it's hot, do it again and check the differences.

That may lead you to the responsible process.

If nothing is really different, that may be a hidden process. In that case check for malwares / viruses / coin miners.

Also, even if I doubt that it's the cause, check your Windows Update settings. Try for exemple to delay the updates for 7 days and see if it changes something.

Comment: Windows Update would be my guess, and even if you configure your settings correctly, Windows tends to treat them more as suggestions rather than instructions.  At the office, it always runs during "active hours" regardless of anything you try through the front-end, its maddening.